# multiple errors using g++ command line and #include "std_lib_facilities.h"

Tags: c++, gcc

I've see many people talking about this problem, but none seem to be having my issue.

I'm attempting that Programming and Practices 2nd edition text, but when I get to the first program, the Hello World! one, it returns a whole bunch of errors when using the std_lib_facilities.h file provided on Stroustrup's support website: http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/

I don't mind not even using the file, but I have too at this point because I won't know which inclusions I'm supposed to put when he uses that header.

I downloaded g++/gcc through cygwin and am using Windows 10 Pro. At installation, I manually selected the gcc/g++, gdc, and make, I believe were the ones. For certain, I selected the gcc/g++ and make options. I am actually trying to compile this using the command prompt:
g++ -o filename sourcefile.cpp or gcc -o filename sourcefile.cpp

The following is the actual file itself, copied and pasted,
followed by the source code I'm using, 
followed by the errors I'm getting, up to and including the line with the typed command,
followed by the version of my g++ and gcc as typed in the command prompt: g++ --version
gcc --version

The std_lib_facilities.h file:
http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/PPP2code/std_lib_facilities.h

```
/*
   std_lib_facilities.h
*/

/*
    simple "Programming: Principles and Practice using C++ (second edition)" course header to
    be used for the first few weeks.
    It provides the most common standard headers (in the global namespace)
    and minimal exception/error support.

    Students: please don't try to understand the details of headers just yet.
    All will be explained. This header is primarily used so that you don't have
    to understand every concept all at once.

    By Chapter 10, you don't need this file and after Chapter 21, you'll understand it

    Revised April 25, 2010: simple_error() added

    Revised November 25 2013: remove support for pre-C++11 compilers, use C++11: <chrono>
    Revised November 28 2013: add a few container algorithms
    Revised June 8 2014: added #ifndef to workaround Microsoft C++11 weakness
*/

#ifndef H112
#define H112 251113L


#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<fstream>
#include<sstream>
#include<cmath>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<string>
#include<list>
#include <forward_list>
#include<vector>
#include<unordered_map>
#include<algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <regex>
#include<random>
#include<stdexcept>

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------


//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

typedef long Unicode;

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

using namespace std;

template<class T> string to_string(const T& t)
{
    ostringstream os;
    os << t;
    return os.str();
}

struct Range_error : out_of_range { // enhanced vector range error reporting
    int index;
    Range_error(int i) :out_of_range("Range error: "+to_string(i)), index(i) { }
};


// trivially range-checked vector (no iterator checking):
template< class T> struct Vector : public std::vector<T> {
    using size_type = typename std::vector<T>::size_type;

#ifdef _MSC_VER
    // microsoft doesn't yet support C++11 inheriting constructors
    Vector() { }
    explicit Vector(size_type n) :std::vector<T>(n) {}
    Vector(size_type n, const T& v) :std::vector<T>(n,v) {}
    template <class I>
    Vector(I first, I last) : std::vector<T>(first, last) {}
    Vector(initializer_list<T> list) : std::vector<T>(list) {}
#else
    using std::vector<T>::vector;   // inheriting constructor
#endif

    T& operator[](unsigned int i) // rather than return at(i);
    {
        if (i<0||this->size()<=i) throw Range_error(i);
        return std::vector<T>::operator[](i);
    }
    const T& operator[](unsigned int i) const
    {
        if (i<0||this->size()<=i) throw Range_error(i);
        return std::vector<T>::operator[](i);
    }
};

// disgusting macro hack to get a range checked vector:
#define vector Vector

// trivially range-checked string (no iterator checking):
struct String : std::string {
    using size_type = std::string::size_type;
//  using string::string;

    char& operator[](unsigned int i) // rather than return at(i);
    {
        if (i<0||size()<=i) throw Range_error(i);
        return std::string::operator[](i);
    }

    const char& operator[](unsigned int i) const
    {
        if (i<0||size()<=i) throw Range_error(i);
        return std::string::operator[](i);
    }
};


namespace std {

    template<> struct hash<String>
    {
        size_t operator()(const String& s) const
        {
            return hash<std::string>()(s);
        }
    };

} // of namespace std


struct Exit : runtime_error {
    Exit(): runtime_error("Exit") {}
};

// error() simply disguises throws:
inline void error(const string& s)
{
    throw runtime_error(s);
}

inline void error(const string& s, const string& s2)
{
    error(s+s2);
}

inline void error(const string& s, int i)
{
    ostringstream os;
    os << s <<": " << i;
    error(os.str());
}


template<class T> char* as_bytes(T& i)  // needed for binary I/O
{
    void* addr = &i;    // get the address of the first byte
                        // of memory used to store the object
    return static_cast<char*>(addr); // treat that memory as bytes
}


inline void keep_window_open()
{
    cin.clear();
    cout << "Please enter a character to exit\n";
    char ch;
    cin >> ch;
    return;
}

inline void keep_window_open(string s)
{
    if (s=="") return;
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(120,'\n');
    for (;;) {
        cout << "Please enter " << s << " to exit\n";
        string ss;
        while (cin >> ss && ss!=s)
            cout << "Please enter " << s << " to exit\n";
        return;
    }
}



// error function to be used (only) until error() is introduced in Chapter 5:
inline void simple_error(string s)  // write ``error: s and exit program
{
    cerr << "error: " << s << '\n';
    keep_window_open();     // for some Windows environments
    exit(1);
}

// make std::min() and std::max() accessible on systems with antisocial macros:
#undef min
#undef max


// run-time checked narrowing cast (type conversion). See ???.
template<class R, class A> R narrow_cast(const A& a)
{
    R r = R(a);
    if (A(r)!=a) error(string("info loss"));
    return r;
}

// random number generators. See 24.7.



inline int randint(int min, int max) { static default_random_engine ran; return uniform_int_distribution<>{min, max}(ran); }

inline int randint(int max) { return randint(0, max); }

//inline double sqrt(int x) { return sqrt(double(x)); } // to match C++0x

// container algorithms. See 21.9.

template<typename C>
using Value_type = typename C::value_type;

template<typename C>
using Iterator = typename C::iterator;

template<typename C>
    // requires Container<C>()
void sort(C& c)
{
    std::sort(c.begin(), c.end());
}

template<typename C, typename Pred>
// requires Container<C>() && Binary_Predicate<Value_type<C>>()
void sort(C& c, Pred p)
{
    std::sort(c.begin(), c.end(), p);
}

template<typename C, typename Val>
    // requires Container<C>() && Equality_comparable<C,Val>()
Iterator<C> find(C& c, Val v)
{
    return std::find(c.begin(), c.end(), v);
}

template<typename C, typename Pred>
// requires Container<C>() && Predicate<Pred,Value_type<C>>()
Iterator<C> find_if(C& c, Pred p)
{
    return std::find_if(c.begin(), c.end(), p);
}

#endif //H112
```

The source code I'm using:

```
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"

int main()
{
    cout << "Programming from Programming Principles and Practice Using C++.\n";
    return 0;
}
```

The errors up to and including the line where I typed the command:
(Note: The same errors seem to occur irrespective of whether I use g++ -o or gcc -o. In this example, it just so happens that I used gcc last.)

```
c:\firstfold\sourcefold>gcc -o frompandphw fromprogprinc_practhw.cpp
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.3.0/include/c++/forward_list:35:0,
                 from std_lib_facilities.h:36,
                 from fromprogprinc_practhw.cpp:1:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.3.0/include/c++/bits/c++0x_warning.h:32:2: error: #error This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support is currently experimental, and must be enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.
 #error This file requires compiler and library support for the \
  ^
In file included from fromprogprinc_practhw.cpp:1:0:
std_lib_facilities.h:71:8: error: expected nested-name-specifier before 'size_type'
  using size_type = typename std::vector<T>::size_type;
        ^
std_lib_facilities.h:82:24: warning: inheriting constructors only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11
  using std::vector<T>::vector; // inheriting constructor
                        ^
std_lib_facilities.h:102:8: error: expected nested-name-specifier before 'size_type'
  using size_type = std::string::size_type;
        ^
std_lib_facilities.h:121:23: error: 'hash' is not a class template
     template<> struct hash<String>
                       ^
std_lib_facilities.h:122:5: error: explicit specialization of non-template 'std::hash'
     {
     ^
std_lib_facilities.h: In member function 'std::size_t std::hash::operator()(const String&) const':
std_lib_facilities.h:125:20: error: 'std::hash' is not a template
             return hash<std::string>()(s);
                    ^
std_lib_facilities.h: In function 'int randint(int, int)':
std_lib_facilities.h:213:47: error: 'default_random_engine' does not name a type
 inline int randint(int min, int max) { static default_random_engine ran; return uniform_int_distribution<>{min, max}(ran); }
                                               ^
std_lib_facilities.h:213:81: error: 'uniform_int_distribution' was not declared in this scope
 inline int randint(int min, int max) { static default_random_engine ran; return uniform_int_distribution<>{min, max}(ran); }
                                                                                 ^
std_lib_facilities.h:213:106: error: expected primary-expression before '>' token
 inline int randint(int min, int max) { static default_random_engine ran; return uniform_int_distribution<>{min, max}(ran); }
                                                                                                          ^
std_lib_facilities.h:213:107: error: expected primary-expression before '{' token
 inline int randint(int min, int max) { static default_random_engine ran; return uniform_int_distribution<>{min, max}(ran); }
                                                                                                           ^
std_lib_facilities.h:213:107: error: expected ';' before '{' token
std_lib_facilities.h:213:116: error: expected ';' before '}' token
 inline int randint(int min, int max) { static default_random_engine ran; return uniform_int_distribution<>{min, max}(ran); }
                                                                                                                    ^
std_lib_facilities.h:213:118: error: 'ran' was not declared in this scope
 inline int randint(int min, int max) { static default_random_engine ran; return uniform_int_distribution<>{min, max}(ran); }
                                                                                                                      ^
std_lib_facilities.h: At global scope:
std_lib_facilities.h:222:1: error: expected unqualified-id before 'using'
 using Value_type = typename C::value_type;
 ^
std_lib_facilities.h:225:1: error: expected unqualified-id before 'using'
 using Iterator = typename C::iterator;
 ^
std_lib_facilities.h:243:1: error: 'Iterator' does not name a type
 Iterator<C> find(C& c, Val v)
 ^
std_lib_facilities.h:250:1: error: 'Iterator' does not name a type
 Iterator<C> find_if(C& c, Pred p)
 ^
```

The versions of g++/gcc:

g++ (GCC) 5.3.0
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

gcc (GCC) 5.3.0
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

Comment: If you want to learn programming, one of the first things you should learn is reading the messages that the compiler is giving you, starting from the top. I've seldom seen a more explicit explanation from a compiler...

Comment: I did, but I couldn't figure out what it was talking about, nor how to differentiate between c++ 11 and c++ whatever the one I'm using is, I assume must be 14. Also, I couldn't figure out the help command to see the command arguments. Also, I'm fairly new to C++.

Comment: `#error This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support is currently experimental, and must be enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.` That was unclear? Or you just couldn't find it among the output?

Comment: I couldn't figure out what to do with it. So, I kept trying to figure out what was wrong with the program, the file, and doing google searches to see if anyone else had this problem.

Comment: Obviously, it was simple enough. Mine down there got it pretty quickly and gave me the answer to my problem. As simple as it might have been, I just couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you need `c++11`, so your compile command should be:
`g++ -std=c++11 -o frompandphw fromprogprinc_practhw.cpp`.

And see if it works.

Comment: 3 HOURS LATER!!!! AND THAT WAS ALL IT WAS!!!! 
Thank you very much!!!!!!

What is the -help command for g++ and gcc. I kept trying different ones, but couldn't seem to get the list of command arguments for g++ or gcc.

Comment: Actually you should notice the error `#error This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011...`

Comment: Yeah, I saw that, but I couldn't figure out what to do with it. I downloaded it through Cygwin, and this is my first time trying to figure out how to use g++. It's crazy that it took me so long just for something so simple. I hate when that happens to me.